# Binl error with serva

Tags: windows-xp, windows-installer

I am trying to install Windows XP via network with Serva.

I have set it up using the tutorial I found here: https://mitchtalmadge.com/2015/07/10/using-serva-install-windows-over-network/, but I keep receiving this error:

> [03/22 10:39:03.341] BINL Err: WIA_RIS_SHARE wrong setup; 127.0.0.1:445 SMB_COM_SESSION_SETUP_ANDX NTSTATUS=STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME

Answer (score 2):

Windows XP is a RIS software then you have to create `WIA_RIS_SHARE` which is a [Null Session Share](https://www.vercot.com/~serva/advanced/NullSessionShares.html).

Your error says that Serva BINL engine has failed checking the `WIA_RIS_SHARE`; try re-creating that share correctly.

For installing XP you should read Serva documentation [here](https://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html)